# Best Way to Create Nightly Replication of Sql Server Database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, backup, database-backups, sql-server-agent

I want to create a job that runs every night. I have a database (MyDatabase) that I want to copy/replace my staging database with (MyDatabase_Stage).

I presume the easiest way is to do something related to SQL Server Agent, but I have never done anything like this before. What is the best practice and easiest route to go to get this setup and tested?

I do not care if the data is 24 hours old and the most important criteria is that is does a full copy every night at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

copy the .bak file to your staging server and restore from there using a script.
Run the script on a schedule in an agent job.

The benefit of a script is that you can add functionality later - for instance you might not require audit tables and these can be truncated.

Comment: We had the .bak files automatically created, so I wrote a script to perform a database restore and scheduled it using SQL Server Agent.

Comment: @Brandon, do you happen to have a copy/sample of the script you used that you could share?

Answer (score 1):

Check out snapshot replication.  As part of the setup, it'll create a SQL Agent job to do the copy of the data and whatnot.  You can then schedule that job at whatever time and frequency you like.